# Sum column X based on value in column Y not being in array Z

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

To keep things simple I have 3 columns (place holders used)

X - Contains Revenue
Y - Contains a number (hotel room number)
Z - Independent list of numbers (room numbers belonging to a certain category)

I'm trying to tally all the revenue in column X for rooms that do not appear in Column Z. Here is my attempt:

```
=SUMIFS(X2:X2000,Y2:Y2000,"<>"&Z2:Z198)
```

But that is still totaling all the revenue without the conditional. Pointers?

Comment: Kindly [do not post imaes of sample data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) or [request images of sample data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316945/is-please-post-a-picture-a-non-constructive-comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff).

As a standard formula,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(X2:X2000, --ISERROR(MATCH(Y2:Y2000, Z2:Z198, 0)))
```

Keep column X and column Y references limited to the actual data but the same size. Column Z should likewise be limited but does not necessarily have to be hte same size. Do not use full column references.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, Works like a charm.